# git-deploy with custom ssh key

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to setup [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy) to deploy one of my projects to EC2. Problem is I have to specify a custom ssh key to access the server, which git-deploy doesn't seem to like.

I have configured ssh via ~.ssh/config so that I can just type "ssh myserver" to connect to the EC2 instance.

Here are the commands I executed in order to configure git-deploy:

```
git origin add deploytest myserver:/my/remote/path
git deploy setup -r deploytest
```

The last command asks for a password and then terminates with a **Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed** error.

Comment: Try asking serverfault or superuser, however I will suggest that your .ssh/config file is probably not correct, or your keys are not correct.  Try manually ssh'ing with verbosity set to check things.